# Pre-processor to remove data

Tags: oracle, sed, preprocessor

I have a data in flat file, which contains a trailer which needs to be removed. I am trying to create a external table in oracle and this trailer record needs to be removed before processing the file.

What I have noticed about the file is , the trailer always starts with the string "Note:". I tried to write a oracle preprocessor which will remove all the data after encountering the string "Note:". I wrote it using sed but its not working.

**Please suggest me how can I remove the trailer from the flat file before creating an external table.**

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
/bin/sed -i '/Notes:/Q' "$filename"
```

Above is the sed block i am using.

sample data

|a| 2| 3| 5
    |f| g| h| d
    |d| f| g| g
    |Notes:
    this is the trailer data i want to remove from the file.

Comment: Does that `Note:` contains any other strings or just a `Notes:`?

Comment: It contains only Notes in that line.

Comment: It will not solve the problem. I have about 2 paragraphs of junk text, I need to remove. they occur after the string Notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove lines with keyword starting with `|Notes:` then use

```
sed -i '/^|Notes:/d' file
```

If you want to delete last line irrespective of Notes: keyword,

```
sed -i '$ d' file
```

Suggest you to test both of them outside the script, without `-i` and once satisfied, plug it in the script. Cheers!

Comment: I want to remove all the contents after encountering Notes: in the data. The sed script I am using works file, it is not working as a preprocessor in oracle.

Comment: You mentioned `I wrote it using sed but its not working.` and now you are telling that it is working?

Comment: The sed command is working file as a standalone script but fails to work as a oracle preprocessor.